# trying to distribute the numbers to each other in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to take a list like this

```
[ 2, 14, 275, 10000, 1, 45]
```

and distribute and subtract from the large values to add to numbers to equal the same thing

for example

```
[5, 10, 6]
```

would equal

```
[7, 7, 7]
```

Comment: In the case of `[5,10,6] -> [7,7,7]` - that would only be possible in a case where the average of the numbers is an integer. That criterion doesn't apply to the target set of numbers which sum to 10337. Could you clarify that aspect?

Comment: So do you want your first result to be `[2067,2067,2067,2068,2068]`?

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is a function that takes from the larger numbers and distributes them in a way where in [5, 10, 6] 5 is subtracting 10 - 2, and then 6 is subtracting 8 - 1 to result in [7, 7, 7]

Comment: @Logono: that works for the example case, but will not work for the target set of numbers as there will be two numbers with 2068 and three with 2067 as @TimRoberts has shown. Do you have an example of what the output should be for something like: `[5, 11, 6]`?

Comment: it also needs to result in all numbers in the list being completely the same as each other

Comment: OK - but, it should be noted that would only be possible if the numbers can be floats. Integer solutions will not always be possible. Hence, in the case of the target set of numbers, that should be 2067.4 for each number

Comment: Look, what you're asking for is simply to set the entries of the list equal to the average of the list.  That's it.  In your first case, that would have to be `[2067.4,2067.4,2067.4,2067.4,2067.4]`.  I assume you know how to compute the average.

Comment: @jrd1 it does not have to be a perfect int it can be a float

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes that is what am referring to I am new to python and programming so I am still learning and trying the practice.

Comment: @Logono: alright, then you'll need to calculate the average and create a new list containing N copies of the average, where N is the length of the input list

Comment: `out = [sum(data)/len(data)] * len(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from statistics import mean

def distribute(l):
    return [mean(l)]*len(l)

x = [ 2, 14, 275, 10000, 1, 45]
y = [5, 10, 6]

new_x = distribute(x)
new_y = distribute(y)

print(new_x)
print(new_y)
```

Output:

```
[1722.8333333333333, 1722.8333333333333, 1722.8333333333333, 1722.8333333333333, 1722.8333333333333, 1722.8333333333333]
[7, 7, 7]
```

Comment: The main benefit of using `statistics.mean` is that it'll return an integer rather than a float if applicable~

Comment: why would you even use mean, when it's something so easy to compute

Comment: Besides the reason I commented already, another reason would be readability. `mean(x)` is easier to read and understand than `sum(x)/len(x)`

Answer (score 2):

```
data = [5, 10, 6]
output = [sum(data)/len(data)] * len(data)
print(output)
```

output :

```
[7.0, 7.0, 7.0]
```